# Java Returning a New Object *Complete Beginner

Tags: java, oop, object, methods

I am going to ask hopefully an easy question and I apologize in advance for any wording issues. I have a custom products class which works without an issue, within another class I create an array of products. see below:

```
 products = new product[10];
 product_count = 0;
```

I now wish to write a method to return not only the array of products but also the product_count, is it possible to return both as a new object? - if not could someone even show me how to return an object. I apologise if this seems a stupid question I am merely trying to learn, and thanks for any advice in advance

**thanks for all the responses - now I will throw a spanner in the works - I am trying to implement this method using java RMI - does anyone have an idea of how this would function?

Comment: Tip: it's almost always better to use a Collection instead of an array--e.g., `List<Product> lstProducts = new ArrayList<Product>();`

Comment: For RMI - take care to use Serializable objects for communication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this to return your array:

```
public product[] returnArray(){
   return products;
}
```

Keep in mind that you can just update your `product_count` instead of returning it.

Comment: This code seems to be invalid. The products is the variable, the return value should be product[], although the op clearly stated (s)he needs multiple values to return, not just the array.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays know their own length.  There's no need to return a length and the array separately.  Just read the `length` field:

```
Product[] products = new Product[10];
System.out.println("The size of products is " + products.length);
```

Note that I capitalized the type name `Product`.  Common convention in Java is for all class names to start with an uppercase letter.

Answer (score 1):

Returning a single object can be done using `return`: `return referenceName;`

Returning multiple objects is easiest if you create your own class for it, or check for already existing implementations that might fit your use case. For example see: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry.html